# Audio classification without deep learning

Tags: audio-processing, classification

I am looking for code or papers, for methods to classify audio signals, without the use of deep neural networks (DNN).
A current paper which reviews methods will also be most welcome.
I have searched google scholar for such a paper to no avail.

To make it clearer, I am looking to compare against the state of the art. I have researched ESC-50 and DCASE but all best-achieving methods there are DNN. I want to compare my work against a classical algorithm in a paper. For that purpose, I need either a reliable source that reviews current methods and relieves the need to compare against them or something that is the current, state-of-the-art, classic method. deems classical methods not

Are there any such methods?

Comment: Well, yes, there are. Look basically into any audio classification, speech recognition … textbook. This is a rather mature field! So, no wonder you don't find that many papers, it's textbook knowledge! Probably, Rabiner's classic (~1989) "Tutorial on hidden markov models" and select topics in speech recognition or so is something you'll want to read.

Comment: I am familiar with HMM as a speech recognition system, but can it be a general audio classifier? can it distinguish between crying-babies, coughs, and toilet flashes audio segments? If so, do you have a reference for such a method?

Comment: Found the correct reference and a reprint: [L.R. Rabiner *A tutorial on hidden Markov models and selected applications in speech recognition*, 1989](https://web.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/tutorial%20on%20hmm%20and%20applications.pdf)

Comment: Well, yes, the model doesn't really care about what you build it against. If you don't know the classes beforehand, you've got a classical clustering problem (on e.g. feature vectors made of MFCCs), and from k-means to SVDs, there's a lot of classical things :)

Answer (score 3):

From what you've mentioned it looks like the task is for environmental sound event detection. I think that the best starting point for you is to check the [DCASE challenge](http://dcase.community/events) (Detection and Classification of Acoustic Scenes and Events). The result pages are amazing - you can sort all systems by their performance, classifier being used, features, etc.

For example [this is from 2019](http://dcase.community/challenge2019/task-sound-event-detection-in-domestic-environments-results).
[image]

Comment: Environmental sound event detection is not audio classification.

Comment: You wanted to distinguish between baby cry, cough, etc. right? Then it's a SED task.

Comment: Sound event detection and audio environment classification are not the same. I am looking for SED, though, if you noticed, all of the methods submitted to DCASE have some sort of DNN included.

Comment: I think that in the case of detecting acoustic events that you've mentioned it's pretty much the same.You've got audio file/stream and want to detect whether it belongs to a particular class or what are the events present in it. At the end of the day, the classifier will make that decision for you.
As for variation of model architectures, you are right - pretty much everyone jumped on NN bandwagon and organizers were like "fine, that's what it is - there's plenty of data. for it". There are some papers there which use GMM's, Random Forrests, kNN's, template matchine, etc. if you look further.

Comment: You are correct in saying that a classifier is a classifier. I will not choose your answer, though, because the classical methods there have poor achievments with respect to DNN methods. I have edited my question to emphasize what kind of method I am looking for.

Comment: Well, that's the reality - people mainly used DNN's right now so any SOTA is pretty much DNN based. Not much research is going into other model architectures.